# VNC to Solaris 11 Express blocked on reboot by keychain authorization prompt

Tags: solaris, vnc, keychain

So I just setup a box running Solaris Express 11 to use as a ZFS server for the home network and I have a small issue with the built-in VNC server.

On a fresh reboot if I try and log in via VNC the client hangs. If I switch the monitor over to the solaris box it is hanging at a prompt requesting authorization to the keychain (so it can verify my VNC password). Once I have entered authentication once via the local console it works fine. It's only really come up as I've been rebooting more often trying to get the hang of the services mechanism, but it's mildly annoying still.

Do I just need to setup a different remote server, or is there some way I can configure the existing one  (I do want to stay with something that requires some sort of authorization (password, user pass, or some sort of token)).  Would like windows & os X clients.

Comment: Is this that gnome keyring?  I haven't tried 11 express yet.

Comment: Yep, the Gnome keyring

Comment: My solution so far for gnome keyring has been just to disable it.  It seems like it's really only designed for a desktop system.

Comment: Doh, for some reason didn't consider that.  If you want to post it as a reply I'll accept it as the answer (I'll test it out this afternoon when I get off of work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling gnome keyring didn't work, but I did finally get this going.  For the sake of completeness, to be able to VNC into my Solaris 11 Express box after a server restart without first needing to go to the local console I had to

1)Turn on GDM autologin
in /etc/gdm/custom.conf I had to add under the [daemon] header
    AutomaticLoginEnable=true
    AutomaticLogin=username
    GdmXserverTimeout=15

2)Remove the password from the gnome keychain
    go to package manager and search for "seahorse"
    install/run
    right click on the "Default" keychain and change password to a blank password.

Now finally I can VNC into my box without having to login to the local console first after a restart.